# error ts2315 type 'observable' is not generic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting

> type 'observable is not generic'

though importing files. I am trying CRUD operation in angular 7 and made two components that are add and list of employees, and my function for creating and getting employee list is written in "policy.service.ts", where I am getting

> type 'Observable' is not generic

I am not getting where I am doing wrong, Please help to resolve this

This is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "crudop",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.8.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~3.2.2"
    }
}
```

#### policy.service.ts

```
import {
    Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
    HttpHeaders
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
    IEmployee
} from './Iempolyee';
import {
    Observable
} from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PolicyService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    private url = 'api/employees';

    getEmployees(): Observable < IEmployee[] > {
        return this.http.get < IEmployee[] > (this.url)
    }

    createUseremployee(user: IEmployee): Observable < IEmployee > {
            const httpOptions = {
                    headers: new HttpHeaders({
                            'Content- 
                            Type ':'
                            application / json '})}
                            return this.http.post < IEmployee > (this.url, user, httpOptions);
                        }

                    }
```

Here I am getting issue for `getEmployee` and `createUseremployee` function that type observable is not generic.

I am thinking if I need to reinstall all or any trick can work

[policyservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uR0D.png)

Comment: Please make sure you're importing `Observable` from the `rxjs` package.  it's also worth noting this return type annotations are redundant in this context. Oh and it looks like your version of rxjs doesn't match your version of rxjs compat

Comment: Hi Aluan, how is matching both version will work?

Comment: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` and also you don't need `rxjs-compat`

Comment: Hi Sourav, I have done that also but it is not working

Answer (score 4):

you need add {} for Observable and only import from rxjs

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

this work for me

```
import {  Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface IEmployee {
   id:number
}


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PolicyService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
private url = 'api/employees';

getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.url)
}

createUseremployee(user: IEmployee): Observable<IEmployee> {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type ': 'application / json '
        })
    }
    return this.http.post<IEmployee>(this.url, user, httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: Sure I will upload it

Comment: Hi @renato, U can see above in question one link is there 'policyservice' click that u will get the screenshot

Comment: you can try this:
1.- delete "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2" from package.json, 
2.- delete node_modules
3.- execute npm clean cache --force,
4.- npm install

Comment: Hi @renato, this is also not working out , Thanks for help